# Why doesn't writing to /dev/fb0 work on some video cards

Tags: linux, bash, linux-kernel, framebuffer

I have a simple embedded Linux build that boots from a USB and has a framebuffer.  There are simple bash scripts that write to the /dev/fb0 device to give user feedback and clear the screen,  along with the utility fbv to display images.  This works great on most systems but on some hardware writing directly to /dev/fb0 doesn't produce anything.  I know the video is working because using the fbv utility to display images to the screen does work but writing pixel data directly to /dev/fbv using dd does not.

why does writing directly in a bash script to /dev/fb0 work on some machines but not others?

Edit: the hardware in question is a Supermicro motherboard with one of those integrated Aspeed AST graphics controllers.  The video mode is 1280x1024 which is native resolution for the monitor I have attached.  Linux Kernel is the latest 4.19.x

Comment: Please add specifics: hardware models, current video mode, etc. to your question

Comment: This is not a programming question.  It is about hardware and device drivers (and the OS).  Try asking on the UNIX & Linux SE site, or on SuperUser.

Comment: It's a programming question because I wrote a program and it isn't working.